# How do you use tiks to draw a labeled time scale with no number line in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am attempting to draw the following labeled time scale using the tikz package in LaTex:

[image: the time scale I am trying to draw with tikz]

I used the following code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[*-*] (0,0) -- node[midway,above] {a} ++ (1,0);
    \draw (1,0) node[midway,above] {b} (3,0);
    \draw[*-*] (3,0) -- node[midway,above] {c} ++ (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and this was the result:

[image: the result of what I tried]

which is clearly not what I was aiming for. I've tried a few other methods, but this was the closest.

I am aware that there are many many answered questions about tikz on the site, but I haven't been able to find any cases where there are breaks between intervals and the labels do not have vertical lines. Does anybody have any recommendations? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not the best way to achieve this, especially if you have to do this repeatedly, but it's a good way to understand the syntax, if you're in your way to learn Ti*k*Z.

`\path` creates a path from one point to another, but doesn't draw it (except if you write `\path[draw]`).

`\draw` does exactly the same as `\path[draw]`, it creates a path and draws it.
What you did by placing nodes at the `midway` was OK but it's better to do that after your path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Circle-Circle] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[midway,above] {a};
    \path (1,0) -- (2,0) node[midway,above] {b} ;
    \draw[Circle-Circle] (2,0) -- (3,0) node[midway,above]{c};
    \path (3,0) -- (4,0) node[midway,above] {d} ;
    \draw[Circle-Circle] (4,0) -- (5,0) node[midway,above]{e};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: paths and nodes]

Comment: Thank you! You mentioned this is not the best way, what would be?

Comment: If you have to do this repeatedly, you would definitely consider doing it with a `foreach` loop, even if it involves some calculations.